Demote a group milestone to a project milestone in GITLAB
I have a question regarding milestone in gitlab.
I know that it is possible to promote a project milestone to a group milestone, but I was wondering if the opposite is also possible.
I would like to downgrade a group milestone to a single project. Is that possible? I could not find an obvious way on the web interface.
Thanks for your help.
